# Getting the IMEI for a iDevice without linking in the IOKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, imei

I am trying to get the IMEI of the ipad the code is running on but I don't want to link it un to the application there for I want to dynamically load the IOKit.

I found some code around and converted it to this and I tested it on a IPhone 4s and it dident work can anybody see any reason why this code is not working ??

PS my app is not available through the app store only as an enterprise app.

```
mach_port_t          masterPort;
CFTypeID             propID = (CFTypeID) NULL;
unsigned int         bufSize;

void *IOKit = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/IOKit", RTLD_NOW);

if(IOKit)
{
    kern_return_t (*kIOMasterPort)( mach_port_t bootstrapPort,mach_port_t * masterPort ) = dlsym(IOKit,"IOMasterPort");

    io_registry_entry_t (*kIORegistryGetRootEntry)(mach_port_t  masterPort ) = dlsym(IOKit,"IORegistryGetRootEntry");

    CFTypeRef (*kIORegistryEntrySearchCFProperty)(io_registry_entry_t   entry,const io_name_t       plane,CFStringRef       key,CFAllocatorRef      allocator, IOOptionBits     options ) =
    dlsym(IOKit,"IORegistryEntrySearchCFProperty");

    kern_return_t kr = kIOMasterPort(MACH_PORT_NULL, &masterPort);

    io_registry_entry_t entry = kIORegistryGetRootEntry(masterPort);

    CFTypeRef prop = kIORegistryEntrySearchCFProperty(entry, "IODeviceTree", (CFStringRef) @"device-imei" , nil, kIORegistryIterateRecursively);

    propID = CFGetTypeID(prop);

    CFDataRef propData = (CFDataRef) prop;
    if (!propData) return nil;

    bufSize = CFDataGetLength(propData);
    if (!bufSize) return nil;

    NSString *p1 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:CFDataGetBytePtr(propData) length:bufSize encoding:1] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"foo %@" ,p1);
    return [p1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\0"];
}

// kern_return_t kr = IOMasterPort(MACH_PORT_NULL, &masterPort);

return nil;
```